# Which git version does 'go get' use when multiple git are available in $PATH?

Tags: git, go

I have a system installed `/usr/bin/git` and a local `~/bin/git`. Both are in `$PATH`.

- Which git will `go get ...` use? I'm assuming the first one it can find in `$PATH`, which usually would be `/usr/bin/git`.
- Is there a way to force `go get ...` to use a git binary from a different path and not the first one it can find? e.g. `~/bin/git` or `/some/other/path/to/git`.

Comment: Why would you want to have multiple git in the path ?

Comment: I'm tempted to ask "what is 'go' in this context?" because without knowing that, the question is somewhat insoluble.  Often, programs will find the first executable in a path; this is the default behaviour when the name invoked is just `git` without a path component.  However, it might be that `go` is configured to prefix the name `git` with a path, in which case, the result will be different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the question is tagged with 'go' so I assume the context is the same as the tag.

Comment: I've not used Go language sufficiently recently, I guess; I'm pretty sure there wasn't a 'go' command when I was using it (ouch - that was late 2009 or early 2010, I think; long before version 1.0, let alone 1.3).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/).

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza One main reason is to use a newer version of git than is available in the repos. The second reason is "just because" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an alias for go where you set the path environment like you want.

Then it will run in that environment, and won't be concerned with your environment.

As you stated, you created an alias like this:

```
alias go="env GOROOT=$HOME/go GOPATH=$HOME/gocode GOBIN=$HOME/gocode/bin PATH=$HOME/go/bin:$HOME/bin:$GOBIN:$PATH $HOME/go/bin/go"
```

Comment: I used your answer to create a bash alias with its own environment. `alias go="env GOROOT=$HOME/go GOPATH=$HOME/gocode GOBIN=$HOME/gocode/bin PATH=$HOME/go/bin:$HOME/bin:$GOBIN:$PATH $HOME/go/bin/go"`. To explain a little bit more, Go is installed in $HOME/go, GOPATH is $HOME/gocode, local git is installed in $HOME/bin.